# Create Json Array in C# using foreach loop

Tags: c#, arraylist

Presently I am assigning value manual to productid

```
 product_items = new List<Messages.Catalogue.MultiProduct.ProductItem>()
                                {
                                   
                                                                                                      
                                    new Messages.Catalogue.MultiProduct.ProductItem
                                    {
                                        productid="8906010000000"
                                    },
                                      new Messages.Catalogue.MultiProduct.ProductItem
                                    {
                                        productid="8906007280969"
                                    }
                                }
```

I want assigning the productid value using forloop from ArrayList, How to do that

Comment: The question is ... bx ehivh pattern / logic/ algorithm, do you want to assign a product id to an item? Random string? Guids?

Comment: It's probably easier to use LINQ. For example, assuming your arraylist has productid strings in it: `prod_items = productIdArrayList.Cast<string>().Select(id => new ProductItem{ productid = id }).ToList();`

Comment: arraylist is product table contains id, name, rate and many more